# how to add a jsonmodel object to NSArray

Tags: ios, jsonmodel

I am using jsonmodel :

```
- (NSMutableArray *)ChildIntRecursiveWithChannels:(Channels *)channels  
                                           depths:(NSMutableArray *)depths 
                                           number:(int)number {

    NSLog(@"channels.name:%@",channels.name);

    [nodeArray addObject:channels]; 

    return  depths;
}
```

I'm getting the log:channels.name:aaaa, but get the channels from channels is null;

and i modify

```
- (NSMutableArray *)ChildIntRecursiveWithChannels:(Channels *)channels  
                                           depths:(NSMutableArray *)depths 
                                           number:(int)number {

    Channels * tempChannels ;

    tempChannels.name=channels.name;
    NSLog(@"tempChannels.name:%@",tempChannels.name);

    return  depths;
}
```

but the tempChannels.name also is null can you give some advice?

Comment: is channels ever *not* null in either of those methods?

Comment: Your question is too vague, can you share the json structure and the data that you are trying to add.

Comment: i am sure channels not is null;because channels.name have value. but when put the channels to the tempChannels tempChannels.name is null

Comment: did you alloc init nodeArray??

Comment: so what was the solution?

Comment: i cannot init  the nodeArray,youcan put it as the answer